# Hardcoded app:fragment string in Preference crashes in Release

Tags: android, xml, kotlin, jvm

Below is the simplified version of the xml file for my settings screen.

```
<androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <!--hardcoded app:fragment crashes in release because of ClassNameNotFound -->
    <Preference
        app:allowDividerAbove="true"
        app:fragment="com.flamyoad.tsukiviewer.ui.settings.preferences.ClearDataPreferences"
        app:icon="@drawable/ic_delete_settings_24dp"
        app:title="Clear data" />

</androidx.preference.PreferenceScreen>
```

It works well in debug version. But when I click on the preference on release apk, it crashes because of `ClassNotFoundException`.

Stacktrace here

```
Process: com.flamyoad.tsukiviewer, PID: 13647
    androidx.fragment.app.Fragment$c: Unable to instantiate fragment com.flamyoad.tsukiviewer.ui.settings.preferences.ClearDataPreferences: make sure class name exists
        at i.l.d.n.d()
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.a()
        at i.l.d.r$c.a(:2)
        at com.flamyoad.tsukiviewer.ui.settings.SettingsActivity.a(:2)
        at i.s.f.b(:29)
        at androidx.preference.Preference.a(:23)
        at androidx.preference.Preference$a.onClick()
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4757)
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19769)
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694)
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.flamyoad.tsukiviewer.ui.settings.preferences.ClearDataPreferences
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:308)
        at i.l.d.n.c(:2)
        at i.l.d.n.d() 
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.a() 
        at i.l.d.r$c.a(:2) 
        at com.flamyoad.tsukiviewer.ui.settings.SettingsActivity.a(:2) 
        at i.s.f.b(:29) 
        at androidx.preference.Preference.a(:23) 
        at androidx.preference.Preference$a.onClick() 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4757) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19769) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
     Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: Didn't find class "com.flamyoad.tsukiviewer.ui.settings.preferences.ClearDataPreferences" on path: DexPathList[[zip file "/data/app/com.flamyoad.tsukiviewer-1/base.apk"],nativeLibraryDirectories=[/vendor/lib64, /system/lib64]]
        at dalvik.system.BaseDexClassLoader.findClass(BaseDexClassLoader.java:56)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:511)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:469)
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:308) 
        at i.l.d.n.c(:2) 
        at i.l.d.n.d() 
        at androidx.fragment.app.Fragment.a() 
        at i.l.d.r$c.a(:2) 
        at com.flamyoad.tsukiviewer.ui.settings.SettingsActivity.a(:2) 
        at i.s.f.b(:29) 
        at androidx.preference.Preference.a(:23) 
        at androidx.preference.Preference$a.onClick() 
        at android.view.View.performClick(View.java:4757) 
        at android.view.View$PerformClick.run(View.java:19769) 
        at android.os.Handler.handleCallback(Handler.java:739) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:95) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:135) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5289) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:372) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:899) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:694) 
        Suppressed: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.flamyoad.tsukiviewer.ui.settings.preferences.ClearDataPreferences
        at java.lang.Class.classForName(Native Method)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.findClass(ClassLoader.java:781)
        at java.lang.BootClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:841)
        at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:504)
                ... 21 more
     Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: Class not found using the boot class loader; no stack available
```

To me, it looks like the cause is the apk being minified and class name is replaced with shorter string. What can I do in this situation? Is it best practice to replace the `app:fragment` with function calls in `Activity`? Or is there any other methods?

I'm using `PreferenceFragmentCompat` for my application.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I added these lines into my `proguard-rules.pro` and it stopped crashing.

```
-keep public class * extends androidx.preference.Preference
-keep public class * extends androidx.preference.PreferenceFragmentCompat
```

Answer (score 1):

The [aapt2 generated proguard rules for preferences](https://cs.android.com/android/platform/superproject/+/master:frameworks/base/tools/aapt2/java/ProguardRules.cpp;l=196) specifically look for the `android:fragment` attribute, not `app:fragment`. You'd want to use `android:fragment` to automatically keep preference fragments.

Comment: it still crashes even though I changed from ```app:fragment``` to ```android:fragment```